# Can a VLAN traffic affect other VLANS?

Tags: vlan, bottleneck

Consider 2 vlans

VLAN-1

VLAN-2

VLAN-1 gets an abnormally large traffic spike from outside world.

Will this affect the other VLAN and will the applications in VLAN-2 have packet loss and high latency in this situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VLANs are only logical separation (e.g. several *logical* VLANs can share the same *physical* port).

It is possible that if traffic on one VLAN is saturating your network hardware, it will also affect other ports (and so all other VLANS) on the same hardware.

Answer (score 4):

You experience will depend heavily on the switch configuration and capability. If no QOS (Quality of Service) is configured the you will get degradation on both VLAN.

Not all switches are created equal and can handle packets differently. This section of Wikipedia sums up how switches can handle packets in the part describing the four modes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch#Layer_2